# apps installed but can not find in ubuntu to run the app

Tags: software-installation

I am installing an app in ubuntu named AIrcrack-ng properly. After that, I can not use the app. Because I can not find this app in the background or app list. What should I do? plz, help!

Comment: Aircrack-ng is a command line tool. As such it won't be listed among graphical apps.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Plz, tell me the command line.

Comment: There's NOT one command line. You need to learn how to use the tool: https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=getting_started#using_the_aircrack-ng_suite and follow the relevant links